# Javascript - Parsing JSON including int as Object

Tags: javascript, json, object, int

After several test and search, I can't find a way to navigate after parsing a JSON; here is the post-parsing result :

```
    Object {documentation: "https://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api", licenses: Array[2], rate: Object, results: Array[1], status: Object…}
```

documentation
:
"https://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api"
licenses
:
Array[2]
rate
:
Object
results
:
Array[1]
0
:
Object
annotations
:
Object
components
:
Object
building
:
"C"
city
:
"Bordeaux"
country
:
"France"
country_code
:
"fr"
county
:
"Bordeaux"
postcode
:
"33000"
road
:
"Quai de Bacalan"
state
:
"Aquitaine"
suburb
:
"Bordeaux Maritime"

For example I can get the value of the response with the following code :

```
var locname = response.status.code;
```

But in the case there is a int as Object, like this :

```
var locname = response.results.0.formatted;
```

I have the following error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

I try to escape the character, putting quote, etc but I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since results is an array you must use the following syntax:

```
var locname = response.results[0].formatted;
```

Instead of

```
var locname = response.results.0.formatted;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly;  I'm such a noob !

Comment: @bubu great, then pls mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 1):

in javascript, an object is also accessible as array, so for example, you have an object like this:

```
var obj = {name: 'Hans Yulian', age: 21, message: 'Handsome'};
obj[0] = 'This is an number index';
obj['message'] = 'Too Handsome';
```

all the key is accepted as long as they aren't something that contain special characters (-+=! etc) and not started with number. in any case you have the field that don't satisfy this exception, then you have to access it in array-way.
you can assign the value the same way as array, and also to get the content of that field.

in case you need to access something like

```
var locname = response.results.0.formatted;
```

Then the thing that you need is

```
var locname = response.results[0].formatted;
```

you can try make a html file with this content

```
<script>
    var obj = {name: 'Hans Yulian', age: 21, message: 'Handsome'};
    obj[0] = 'This is an number index';
    obj['message'] = 'Too Handsome';
    obj[1] = {};
    obj[1].name = 'Handsome';
    obj.handsome = [];
    obj.handsome[0] = {};
    obj.handsome[0].hansyulian = 'So Handsome';

    console.log(obj);
    console.log(obj[1].name);
    console.log(obj.handsome[0].hansyulian);
</script>
```

and try see the console(right click, inspect element, select console for google chrome) to understand what happens there

Comment: Thanks Hans, for taking time to answer me; I will go into this in depth with your example !